# Threads with no wait in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am bit new in Java Threading and concurrency. I have read about **synchronized** and **lock** blocks. They let other Threads to wait until first Thread complete its work.

I just want to know a way that if **THREAD A** is performing its execution, then **THREAD B** should not wait and skip the execution of that shared code block.

Comment: For this, you can use `java.util.concurrent.lock.Lock#tryLock` and check if the lock operation was successful. If not, the other thread holds the lock and you can skip.

Comment: If you can give more context, there may be a higher-level solution (such as a lazy-loading cache, or a queue or a scheduler) you can use instead.

Comment: Thank you guys. My bad i just missed this simple thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thread B could try to acquire the lock by [`Lock.tryLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock()). If it's not available, Thread B may skip "the execution of that shared code block" immediately after the check.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know a way that if THREAD A is performing its
>   execution, then THREAD B should not wait and skip the execution of
>   that shared code block.

You can use the two variants of `Lock.tryLock()` one attempts to lock immediately the other waits for a given period:

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
new Thread(() -> {
   boolean isAcquired = lock.tryLock();
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " acquired lock " + isAcquired);
   sleep(10000); //acquires the lock and sleeps for 10 secs
}, "Thread A").start();

sleep(1000); //main thread sleep so that Thread A locks on the lock

new Thread(() ->{
  try {
      //will wait for 2 secs tops to acquire the lock
      boolean isAcquired = lock.tryLock(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " acquired lock " + isAcquired);
  }catch(InterruptedException ie){
      ie.printStackTrace();
  }
}, "Thread B").start();
```

Output:

```
Thread A acquired lock true
Thread B acquired lock false
```

In the first usage the [`tryLock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock()) does not wait it attempts to acquire the lock if it can it will return `true` immediately, else it will return `false`.

In the second usage the [`tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) will wait for the lock to be released for the instructed period of `time` then acquire it and return `true` else it will return `false` or throw `InterruptedException` if it is interrupted.